# How to apply actions to the torrents with a specific tracker in transmission-remote?

Tags: transmission

Transmission supports at least stopping, resuming, removing, removing with the torrent data, moving, queuing and verifying torrents. In the GUI clients (Qt and QTK) it's trivial to filter by a tracker (e.g. archive.org), select all and apply a desired action, but it seems unclear if transmission-remote supports similar accessible batch-functionality.

For reference: `transmission-remote --torrent all --info` outputs information about all of the running torrents, including their trackers.